# Is there a way insert some actions inside a decorated function

Tags: python, decorator

I want to insert some action in a decorated function, but I don't want to touch the codes of that function. Can I insert actions when I define the decorators? Only adding not deleting.

```
def real_decorator(func):
    def __decorator():
        print 'enter the func'
        func() # <- Can I insert some action inside this from here?
        print 'exit the func'
    return __decorator  


@real_decorator
def decorated_function():
    print "I am decorated"


decorated_function()
```

Comment: What do you mean with insert actions? Execute additional code at a specific line inside decorated_function?

Comment: Yes, by accessing the code-frame, but you really want to reconsider your design.  Decorators are meant to be used with *any* function, and adding random code into one could cause untold damage.  So the question is, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
def real_decorator(func):

    def __decorator():
        print 'enter the func'
        for action in __decorator.extra_actions:
            action()
        func()
        print 'exit the func'

    __decorator.extra_actions = []

    return __decorator

@real_decorator
def decorated_function():
    print "I am decorated"

decorated_function()

def new_action():
    print "New action"

decorated_function.extra_actions.append(new_action)

decorated_function()
```